# Equivalence of two Sobolev norms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Define $\|\cdot \|_{H^{s,p}}$ and $\|\cdot \|_{\dot{H}^{s,p}}$ by
$$
\|f\|_{H^{s,p}} := \|(1-\Delta)^{s/2} f\|_{L^p} := \|\mathcal{F}^{-1}( (1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2} \hat{f} (\xi))\|_{L^p}, \\
\|f\|_{\dot{H}^{s,p}} := \||\nabla|^{s} f\|_{L^p} := \|\mathcal{F}^{-1}( |\xi|^s \hat{f} (\xi))\|_{L^p}.
$$
Are $\|\cdot\|_{H^{s,p}}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L^p} + \|\cdot\|_{\dot{H}^{s,p}}$ equivalent norms?
For example, they are obviously equivalent if $p=2$, but I can't prove they are equivalent when $p \neq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are equivalent at least if $s\geq 0$. It follows for example from Mikhlin theorem when $1<p<\infty$. More generally, when $1\leq p\leq \infty$, by Lemma $2$ in Section V$.3.2$ in Stein, *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*, there exists finite measures $\mu_s$, $\nu_s$ and $\lambda_s$ so that their Fourier transform verify
$$
\widehat{\mu}_s(\xi) = \frac{|2\pi\,\xi|^s}{\big(1+|2\pi\,\xi|^2\big)^{s/2}}
\\
\big(1+|2\pi\,\xi|^2\big)^{s/2} = \widehat{\nu}_s(\xi) + |2\pi\,\xi|^s\,\widehat{\lambda}_s(\xi).
$$
From this result, one deduces
$$
\|(-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p} = \|\mu_s*(1-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p}
\\\leq C_{\mu_s}\, \|(1-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p}
$$
where $C_{\mu_s}$ is the total variation of $\mu_s$, and
$$
\|(1-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p} = \|\nu_s*f +\lambda_s*(-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p}
\\\leq C_{\nu_s}\, \|f\|_{L^p} + C_{\lambda_s}\, \|(-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p}.
$$